# Sending email from the specified Outlook Account

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop, mailitem

I am using Outlook2013 which has a number of mailboxes from both exchange and pop servers.(Rob@mydomain.com[default exchange], rob@somethingdifferent.com[POP], support@mydomain.com[exchange])

I am trying to use Outlook automation to send an email using the support@mydomain.com account.

The problem I am having is the below code creates a mail item in the support outbox but the from field is rob@mydomain.com not support@mydomain.com. This stops it from being sent.

I would like to change the from address to support@mydomain.com. I thought that by setting the Sendusingaccount property did this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    public static string Send_Email_Outlook(string _recipient, string _message, string _subject, string _cc, string _bcc, string accountname)
    {
        try
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

            // Get the NameSpace and Logon information.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

            // Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
            oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);

            // Create a new mail item.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            // Set the subject.
            oMsg.Subject = _subject;

            // Set HTMLBody.
            oMsg.HTMLBody = _message;

            oMsg.To = _recipient;
            oMsg.CC = _cc;
            oMsg.BCC = _bcc;


            #region Send via another account

            if (accountname.Trim().Length != 0)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Accounts accounts = oMsg.Session.Accounts;
                for (int i = 1; i <= accounts.Count; i++)
                {
                    string accountfound = accounts[i].DisplayName.ToLower();
                    if (accountname.ToLower() == accountfound)
                    {
                        oMsg.SendUsingAccount = accounts[i]; // Send using support account
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recipient = oMsg.Session.CreateRecipient(accountfound);
                        oMsg.Sender = recipient.AddressEntry;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion

            // Send.
            (oMsg as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem).Send();

            // Log off.
            oNS.Logoff();

            // Clean up.
            //oRecip = null;
            //oRecips = null;
            oMsg = null;
            oNS = null;
            oApp = null;


        }

     // Return Error Message
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

        // Default return value.
        return "";

    }
```

Comment: Try to use the syntax: oMsg.SendUsingAccount = oApp.Session.Accounts.Item(idx). Another possible solution is to create a template email stored as draft, which is using the outlook account of interest: this will require substantial re-coding. Kind regards,

Comment: I have fixed it. I had the mailbox assigned to me in exchange which always made it show up. Once I unassigned the mailbox from my profile and re-added the issue was fixed. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure, you are welcome! Best of luck with your project. Rgds,

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use the [SendUsingAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) property to set up the correct account you need to send items from.

```
 public static Outlook.Account GetAccountForEmailAddress(Outlook.Application application, string smtpAddress) 
 { 

     // Loop over the Accounts collection of the current Outlook session. 
     Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts; 
     foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts) 
     { 
         // When the e-mail address matches, return the account. 
         if (account.SmtpAddress == smtpAddress) 
         { 
            return account; 
         } 
     } 
     throw new System.Exception(string.Format("No Account with SmtpAddress: {0} exists!", smtpAddress)); 
 } 

public static string Send_Email_Outlook(string _recipient, string _message, string _subject, string _cc, string _bcc, string accountname)
{
    try
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

        // Get the NameSpace and Logon information.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

        // Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
        oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true);

        // Create a new mail item.
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        // Set the subject.
        oMsg.Subject = _subject;

        // Set HTMLBody.
        oMsg.HTMLBody = _message;

        oMsg.To = _recipient;
        oMsg.CC = _cc;
        oMsg.BCC = _bcc;


        #region Send via another account

         // Retrieve the account that has the specific SMTP address. 
        Outlook.Account account = GetAccountForEmailAddress(oApp , "support@mydomain.com"); 
        // Use this account to send the e-mail. 
        oMsg.SendUsingAccount = account; 

        // Send.
        (oMsg as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem).Send();

        // Log off.
        oNS.Logoff();

        // Clean up.
        //oRecip = null;
        //oRecips = null;
        oMsg = null;
        oNS = null;
        oApp = null;


    }

 // Return Error Message
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }

    // Default return value.
    return "";

}
```